# Unresolve error for Validators in Spring boot - Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

`user.controller`

```
fun createUser(@Valid() @RequestBody payload: Map<String, String>, @RequestHeader(value = "session") session: String): String { 
    /// code
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
```

I am getting an error `Unresolved reference: Valid`
I have added the starter project for the **hibernate validator**

I have no clue what I am missing?

Comment: what spring boot version are you using?, from spring boot 2.3 you need to add this one too "spring-boot-starter-validation"

Answer (score 3):

Validation is no longer included in recent versions of Spring Boot.

You must add

> starter-validation

library:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
 implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
```